# TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I'm using python version 3.6.

`mystuff.py` includes:

```py
mystuff = {'donut': "SHE LOVES DONUTS!"}
```

`mystuffTest.py` includes this

```py
import mystuff
print (mystuff['donut'])
```

The error that I receive when I run `mystuffTest.py` is as follows:

```
$ python3.6 mystuffTrythis.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mystuffTrythis.py", line 3, in <module>
    print (mystuff['donut'])
TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

So far I haven't seen this exact error here on stackoverflow.  Can anyone explain why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 23):

`import mystuff` is importing the module `mystuff`, not the variable `mystuff`.  To access the variable you'd need to use:

```
import mystuff
print(mystuff.mystuff['donut'])
```

**EDIT:** It's also possible to import the variable directly, using:

```
from mystuff import mystuff
print(mystuff['donut'])
```

Comment: Alternatively, `from mystuff import mystuff` would import the variable, and then you could access it directly as you were doing, i.e. `print(mystuff['donut'])`

Comment: Ok, so from mystuff (module) import mystuff (variable).  Ok I can see the pattern, but kind of confusing myself on understanding exactly why this makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @DammondCircuit It's easier to understand if the variable & module have different names. I.e. mymodule.myvariable.  Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful ;)

Comment: Thanks Aaron.  You are right about that.  I will keep this in mind going forward.

Comment: This is such an annoying "feature" of python. That and the whole needing to put a blank file in a directory to import a file from it.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because a later `from __ import *` statement imported a module which bound my variable to something else:

```
from stuff_a import d
from stuff_b import *
d['key']
```

In stuff_b.py, `d` was bound to a module, hence the error. Lesson learned: avoid importing * from modules.