# Why does this error occur while creating a new column in a pandas dataframe? (Module object not subscriptable error)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a retail sales dataset and I am trying to create a new column in it using the mutate function under "dfply" package.

The dataset is a dataframe named 'data' and the column I'm trying to create is named 'date_diff'(difference between dates) I have tried running the following code in my Jupyter notebook:

```
(data >>
mutate(
date_diff=data['InvoiceDate'] - log(data['InvoiceDate'])
))
```

The result I am expecting is a new column called date_diff added to the existing dataframe, but this is the output I am getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-3035c41fde12> in <module>
      1 (data >>
      2 mutate(
----> 3 date_diff=data['InvoiceDate'] - log(data['InvoiceDate'])
      4 ))

TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

I have seen this error being referenced here too: [TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147823/typeerror-module-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Is the answer given in the above question applicable to my problem too? Or does my problem require a different approach?

Comment: How do you import pandas?

Comment: the error: "xxx object is not subscriptable" basically means you tried to call `xxx[something]` and xxx doesn't support indexing data. Sort of  like if you created an integer: `a = 5` and then tried to call `a['test']` you should get the same error.

Comment: @Hoog import pandas as pd

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `data` is not a Pandas DataFrame. Check how you assigned `data` to your data.

Comment: Used this for creating dataframe: data=pd.read_excel    When I type data.info(), it gives me <class pandas.core.frame.DataFrame>